# Does similar equipment stack in Resident Evil Resistance?

Tags: resident-evil-resistance

Does the equipment (perks) stack?

So for example is there any benefit in having Iron Nails 1, 2 **and** 3 all equipped at the same time, or will it just use the highest?

The fact it allows it to be done suggests yes, but it doesn't seen to say so not sure, and can't think of best way to test for myself either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, equipment do stack.

I confirmed using FMJ Rounds on Becca.

Here my results after several tests on practice mode.
Damage on zombies.

FMJ Rounds II : Highest weapon damage was 446
FMJ Rounds III : Highest weapon damage was 462
FMJ Rounds II & III : Highest weapon damage was 503

As you can see, same equipment stack with each other.
Iron Nails should be the same but on melee damage.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing as January with EMP Rounds I & II equipped and there was seemingly no difference in damage dealt to cameras for me. The Mastermind was Spencer. Not sure if some Masterminds can buff the cameras, but that might explain why there was no change in damage. (Took me 7 shots with the Quickdraw Army to take out one active camera)